# Difficulties with python subprocess? (Unable to run wp-cli commands)

Tags: python, wordpress, wp-cli

I am writing a simple Python script to help expedite bootstrapping my Wordpress installs and making use of [wp-cli](https://github.com/wp-cli/wp-cli)

I'm stuck at a point where I'm trying to call `wp core download` via a subprocess:

```
from subprocess import call
call(["wp", "core download"])
```

Which always returns

> Error: This does not seem to be a WordPress install.
>   Pass --path=`path/to/wordpress` or run `wp core download`.

Simply running the above from the python console nor from my script does not work.

Running the command directly in the shell works, of course.

I've also tried setting the PWD with `os.chdir` and also passing the explicit directory with the `--path=...` argument to no avail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Function [`subprocess.call`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) takes as an argument list of parameters so in you case proper call should be:

```
call(["wp", "core", "download"])
```

Maybe for you it's better to use [`subprocess.Popen`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen) which takes as argument `cwd` even though its usage isn't as simple as just `subprocess.call`.

If none of this helps maybe try running just `call(["pwd"])` to see if setting CWD using `os.chdir` works as you expect.